# C++ template library for calculate continuous signals

Tags: c++, templates

I'm looking for a C++ template library which implements operations on continuous signals represented in integer types with their resolutions (fixed point numbers).

e.g: foo, bar, baz are int with 10, 5 and 2 count/unit resolution

```
foo = 4;
bar = 3;
baz = foo * bar;
printf("%d %d %d\n", foo, bar, baz);
```

results:
40 15 24

(foo = 4 * 10, bar = 3 * 5, baz = foo / 10 * bar / 5 * 2)

Comment: You mean fixed point numbers?

Comment: Yes, I mean fixed point numbers.

Comment: For clarity, please use *count* rather than *bit* in this context, e.g. 16-*bit* unsigned integers may contain *counts* of between 0-65535.

Comment: no. baz = 3 units *4 units =12 units=24 counts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old C++ library that supports mixing numbers of different precisions. The precisions have to be power of 10.

http://www.efgh.com/software/fixed.htm

If you want math functions (sin, cos, tan) you can try out this library:

http://www.trenki.net/content/view/17/1/

This does not allow you to mix precisions.

Disclaimer: I haven't used any of these !